# Efficient way to load and display amimation (a set of Drawable frames)

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I need to display an animation consisting of 3 `drawable` resources cycled about 5 times per second. What I use right now is `ImageView`, and the drawables are loaded into a `Bitmap[3]` array pre-scaled. The original size of the resources is 2000x2000 px, and I've learnt that I can only downscale to as low as 500 px before the image starts looking terrible.

The animation itself looks smooth (i. e. it takes less than 200 ms per frame so there's no visible lag), but takes up quite a bit of CPU. And the real problem is loading and scaling the 3 bitmaps: it takes 2-3 seconds.

I am now working on a way to do the loading asynchronously in a background thread, but I wonder if there's a better way altogether. One less demanding of CPU, for one. And I'd also like to use slightly larger (less downscaled) bitmaps for large high-density screens.

Answer (score -1):

From your description it seems that the problem resides with the size of the images, rather than the animation itself.

For animation assets this large - I would suggest encoding a video in a format that supports gradual loading and streaming from it.